# Set value of mail address input is not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fill a text input of email address in [signup website](https://mail.tutanota.com/signup)
I got the input element (on the second step after selecting the plan) and set its value to whatever I need by:
`document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = "somemail1231"`
the input was filled but when I press "Next" to continue, it says "Please enter mail address" as the input field was empty.
How can I fix this?

P.S: after some hours of trying I guess its because there is no keyboard button press event, but I'm not sure about that and a simulation of keyboard key press isn't working for me.

Comment: @naveen I'm sorry, whats not understandable in my question?

Comment: rather than pointing to a third party site, please construct a minimal reproducible example here. (I didn't downvote btw)

Comment: @naveen if I could construct a minimal reproducible example I would figure myself whats the problem. I don't actually know how did they (in the third party site) constructed the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fire an event for changes

```js
let input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
input.click() // better than focus for your case
input.value = "sadsad"
var ev = new Event('input')
input.dispatchEvent(ev)
```